# How much PHP for AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm relatively noob to the world of web developpement, and after learning the basics of HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript/jQuery I've started to learn AngularJS.

The problem is that as I am learning AngularJS, I don't understand what will be the point in learning a server-side language like PHP, it seems like AngularJS can do all the job (UI, views, routing, ...)

I think that the only reason would be to store data (but even that, I can use JSON files, no?)
and if it is, how much PHP do I need to learn? (or which parts of the language)

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4):

Angular is a tool for a specific sort of job.  It is not the tool for *every* job, and neither is PHP.

If you are writing an application that can live client-side, then you can certainly generate all of the dynamic components you need with Angular.  There are many web applications out there that are entirely client-side.  There are even more that function client-side and talk to a simple API server for their back-end.

If you are creating a web page that is not interactive, then there is little reason for something like Angular.  There are benefits to having the DOM filled with content ahead of time.  SEO is usually the biggest reason, but you might also consider clients that have disabled JavaScript (if you care about those).

Are you building something that is interactive?  Consider a heavier client-side framework like Angular.  Are you building a web page that is content-driven?  Consider rendering your pages server-side.  In the end, you will likely end up with a mix of both anyway.

Comment: I'm just learning in order to become a web developper, I don't have any project in mind and I just choosed to learn the "newest" technologies, this is the why of the how

Comment: @Mrdx Angular is great for certain types of tasks.  Learn it and build a project or two.  Since you're focused on JavaScript, you might also consider Node.js for the server-side tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but what for the security of my data? Is node+mangodb enough secure?

Comment: @Mrdx Security depends almost entirely on your code.  You can definitely make a bullet-proof Node.js/MongoDB application, just like you can make an insecure Node.js/MongoDB application.

Answer (score 0):

A large consideration is security.  Everything client side is exposed to the world.  If the back end is just data storage without validation or protection except as written inside the client, a malicious user could push whatever data they wanted into your site.  In addition if you are exposing code that is the core of a business inside the client, every user can see that as well.